# Why is there a daily reputation limit of 200 points?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

As a relatively new user, I'm curious about something I read in the help topics about reputation points. The [help text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) states:

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below. Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not subject to the daily reputation limit.…

What is the reason for limiting reputation points to 200 per day?

Comment: So people can will up from the computer at a certain stage ;)

Comment: So people don't earn privileges too quickly for one or two good answers. It gives everyone a bit more of a fair chance.

Comment: It also deals with the reddit effect, so that a post making the runs through social media doesn't give someone 10,000 rep in a single day.

Comment: @Oded: that goal was missed by miles though once people realised that *more accepted answers* could get you more points too..

Comment: @MartijnPieters If by "people" you just mean Jon Skeet, I think one outlier is likely acceptable.

Comment: @Servy Why did I see a Jon Skeet joke coming in this question's comments?

Comment: @Servy: *cough* [Gordon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) *cough*. Or me, for that matter.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, I know; I couldn't resist a touch of hyperbole.  We're still generally talking outlier territory though, given the number of users on the site.

Comment: @Servy I still find it slightly disappointing that my [toaster question](http://superuser.com/questions/792607/why-does-windows-think-that-my-wireless-keyboard-is-a-toaster) has gained me more reputation than hours of dedication to a niche tag on Stack Overflow with lots of detailed answers. And that's with the 200 rep cap. I think I've hit it 8 days out of the last 10.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR That's because your question has been featured in the network-wide "Hot Questions" list. That attracts a *lot* of people. Heck, I clicked on it myself a few days ago while casually browsing Stack Overflow! Gnat has been complaining about the hot questions algorithm for some time now...you can probably find questions about it here on Meta.SO, or maybe on the [global meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ydaetskcoR The toaster find should pair you with Jon Skeet. Obviously, if he wasn't the Chuck Norris of programming.

Comment: Already asked [five years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap).  Everybody has an opinion, none contributed by the guy that actually made the decision :)

Comment: @CodyGray apparently it turned up on Hacker's News, Reddit and was briefly trending on Twitter. Those were probably more important to it's viralilty rather than Hot Network Questions but yeah I agree, I do tend to click on stuff down the side bar into SE sites I'd never normally check.

Comment: @CodyGray So you can imagine the effect that it would have had *without* a reputation cap.  I suppose the better phrasing is that it mitigates the effect of social media; it doesn't (by design) eliminate it entirely.

Comment: Excellent answers and discussion. Thanks to everyone for providing some insight to a new user.

Comment: Does extra rep flow over to the next day?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

There's a reputation cap to [prevent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) [certain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) [users](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) [from](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) [gaining](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) too quickly.

Imagine for a moment that there's no cap and a new user posts his first answer on Stack Overflow. It's a very good answer because the person has been a software developer for decades, and he's proud of it, so he posts something about it on various social media channels: because of its exposure, thousands of people are viewing it each day.

It garners ~500 upvotes and, suddenly, that new user has 5000+ reputation and access to quite a few moderation privileges without actually knowing how to use the site. Said user has access to [the review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review) and can cast close votes: that's a lot of power to give to someone who has only been using Stack Overflow for a couple of days, and it's a major reason that this cap is in place.

Stack Overflow was built to emphasize questions and answers of *lasting value*. One viral answer shouldn't give you thousands of reputation: you should build up a library of questions and answers that people regularly come across in search results and perhaps vote upon, giving you a steady flow of reputation.

It's also to keep the site fair. Those who have reputation in the hundreds of thousands are very good at what they do, and they continue to show that by posting questions and answers, actively contributing to the site. Their posts are often of very high quality and thus attract *many* upvotes in a short period of time. Their reputation would rise so fast that no user who joined today would be able to catch them.

It's a subject of heated debate (take a look at [daily-reputation-limit](/questions/tagged/daily-reputation-limit)), but it's there for a reason.

Comment: It is still strange that those exist: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/218452/high-rep-users-with-only-one-post

Comment: The reputation cap was actually introduced long before there were such things as "moderator privileges". There's been a 200-per-day cap as long as I can remember (which was during the site beta). I was probably one of the first users to reach it (20 August 2008 according to my rep graph).

Comment: @GregHewgill Interesting: I guess the fairness piece comes into play, then.

Comment: @AstroCB no, it isn't about "being fair", it is about recognizing why anyone would actually post an answer: this isn't just for "points" (hence  the rep-cap limit). It is for actually helping the one who asked a question, as I explain below. This is why a selected answer isn't subjected to the rep-cap limit.

Comment: @VonC Well, there are certainly some people who would disagree with you (see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268901/why-is-there-a-daily-reputation-limit-of-200-points/268917?noredirect=1#comment78977_268901) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22449/258672)), but I see what you're saying.

Comment: @AstroCB I agree about the "fairness" aspect though: the fact it incentives posting the right answer doesn't negate the fact it helps level the playing field. I simply think the first criteria is at the very core of what makes those Q&A sites unique.

Comment: This is really very well explained answer. Thank you.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Not sure that query shows that the reputations were earned on same day - it may all be because of same post.

Comment: @WandMaker You're right. It doesn't. It only illustrates that there are users who "gamed" the system despite there being a rep cap. The rep cap shouldn't be the whole solution. I've seen a feature-request to prevent people from gaining reputation for their old and highly viewed posts.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I agree - the early starters have asked and answered all the popular questions already - to build reputations later in the game seems to be more and more difficult

Comment: @akuhn: For future reference, [please do not edit out gender-specific pronouns](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265299/editing-out-gender-pronouns-in-answers).

Comment: @nathantuggy I dare to disagree

Comment: @GregHewgill By my research, it looks like [Michael Stum claimed one on 3 August 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91/michael-stum?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=105), as did [Karl Seguin, albeit with less rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34/karl-seguin?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=39) - though he was a good 5 points shy on August 2nd!! I would be surprised if there are earlier, but who knows!! Interestingly enough, SEDE only gives you 180 for August 20th, though your profile gives 215. Could be some votes have been removed over time which caused it to not show up in the query?

Comment: I really like this quote: "you should build up a library of questions and answers that people regularly come across in search results and perhaps vote upon, giving you a steady flow of reputation." I've always believed stack overflow, and my answers on it, should be this way too: a library I and others can refer to again and again.

Answer (score 76):

As I explain in "[Revisiting the rep cap (yes, again)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136139/6309)", the 200 rep cap is what makes this collection of Q&A site unique:

- if you are an expert, chances are you will get to 20 votes pretty quickly
- **the *only* way to get past that is by putting an answer which isn't simply upvoted, but which *actually answers the question***
  (Meaning: the original poster decides that your answer is the one which solves his/her particular issue)

The site is geared to **incentive experts** not just to post *an* answer (for votes), but **to post *the* answer** (to actually help the one who asked in the first place).

That is the only Q&A site I know which promotes not just posting *good* answers, but the *best* answers.

The daily rep cap is, in that regard, an essential feature, at the very core of what makes the Stack Exchange sites so special (alongside with the votes, putting the best answers on top, and the badges)

Comment: For me this answer sounds much more logical than the accepted one.

Comment: Makes it special. Totally!

Comment: "if you are an expert, chances are you will get to 20 votes pretty quickly." Corollary: There aren't very many experts!

Comment: @VonC Someone did a serial upvoting on my questions and I got +100 rep and already hit the 200 rep limit, and not getting any reps on upvotes, understandable, tomorrow serial upvoting will be reversed, and today's upvotes (after hitting the cap) will be in vain, how do I prevent this?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad From my experience, there is a reconciliation process, and the votes (outside of the serial upvote ones) will count. You can monitor that by saving the page https://stackoverflow.com/reputation now and tomorrow: you should see your "total rep" unaffected by the votes reversal.

Comment: @VonC Thank you so much, you are so awesome sir :)

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I just saw https://stackoverflow.com/users/6618622/copsonroad?tab=reputation: considering the number of serial upvotes, you will see a drop in your total rep, but all the other votes will count (13 or 14 of them, including the ones which have not counted today): so +13/14 upvotes

Comment: @VonC Just to make it clear, let's say so far I got `10(fake) + 13(genuine)` votes, and already limit is reached, and let's assume I get `7` genuine upvotes now (definitely these will not be counted today in my rep tab), so tomorrow will I be able to get `-10+13+7 = 20` votes for today date?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Yes, that should be the case. Again: save a a file the https://stackoverflow.com/reputation between today, and again tomorrow (after the vote reversal): that page is the one displaying your "true" score at all time.

Comment: Sir one last help, I am seeing data in `2  57126622 [10]` form, `10` signifies reputation, but I am not sure what `2` and `57126622` is, I thought `57126622` is post ID or current time in seconds but that's not the case, could you please tell me.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad 57126622 is an answer ID: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57126622. 2 is an upvote. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204036/6309

Comment: Once again thanks a lot sir, you have made my life, glad to see I could talk to the person ranking #2 in Stackoverflow. It's like a dream come true. Many many thanks again!!!

Comment: @CopsOnRoad You are most welcome, and thank you for your contributions and helping others on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @VonC I just saw https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, and found that you were 100% right, yesterday I had `[0]` on 5 post (upvotes after rep limit) and today I can see those post having `(10)`.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Great! Glad it worked out for you. And thanks to Nick Craver, who has worked on reputation before (https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/900827854094708736). Example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211537/6309. From that time (Dec. 2013), the recalc is automatic (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43005/6309)

Answer (score -11):

The 200 reputation limit is a barrier to entry protecting well established users from having to share privileges with other members. It does so by artificially slowing down how quickly competing experts can gain privileges on the site.

The reputation limit has nothing to do with stopping folks from "earning privileges too quickly for one or two good answers". Someone who writes a dozen good answers is still subject to the same overall 200 daily reputation limit as someone who writes a single popular answer. If the concern was to limit one answer from giving someone too much reputation, the reputation limit would be per answer, not per account.

Thanks to the 200 reputation limit, old time contributors of the site can enjoy the exclusivity of their elite privileges. The policy does discourage experts new to the site from submitting multiple high quality answers, though.

Comment: If you post just 1334 answers that all are accepted you can earn all privileges in a single day. I don't see how limit for 200 points for upvotes remove initiative to post more answers that actually answer the question...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Upvotes on all answers (included those accepted) are not counted after the 200 point limit. This cap on points remove incentives to posting more answers.

Comment: The daily reputation cap, in its *identical* state, has been in place since nearly the beginning of the site, so it cannot have the purpose that you ascribe to it. Furthermore, it punishes established users just as much as new users; see Jon Skeet as a case study.

Comment: You certainly haven't hit your daily limit ever, it's not like it's keeping you down in any way…

Comment: If I had to come up with a more inflammatory and non-sensical answer than that, I might have to think about it for a while, and if I found one, it might involve illuminati, chemtrails and the flat earth.

Comment: You haven't hit even 100 reputation in a day... why are you complaining.

Comment: @10Rep Yes they have, just not on SO, they hit it on RPG.SE

Comment: @GuillaumeF. Even old time contributors are subject to the rep cap.

Comment: Not too many people care about having priviledges on a site which they don't get paid for and are only doing it to help others. I see more rep farming as of late which even I find a little deplorable.