# Does the daily reputation limit discourage users from asking or answering?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I know why the [daily reputation limit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) exists and I think it should keep that way.

But I think that maybe, some users that get 200 reputation a day because they have tons of answers and questions that keep getting upvotes, may feel a little discouraged to keep answering or asking questions. I know that accepted answers still give reputation, but what about the upvotes or the questions asked?

Should there be a time scale for this or something like that?

If the main reason of the limit is [to prevent certain users from gaining privileges too quickly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268901/why-is-there-a-daily-reputation-limit-of-200-points/268917#268917) then a scale should be appropriate to prevent those cases. I mean, why should the limit affect someone that has been in the site for 5 years (for example) ?

Comment: Jon Skeet would break the reputation counter if the daily limit no longer affected him.

Comment: @juanformoso that does not answer my question. I did not ask why does the limit exist.

Comment: @juanformoso The OP already referred to that, in their question.  They're asking if the limit should still apply to long-time users who have already gained privileges.

Comment: There are multiple reasons for the rep cap, "gaining too quickly" is just one of them.  Nothing about the other ones makes a 'time scale' particularly relevant.  Or practical for that matter, rep calculation is already grossly obtuse and it took a very long time before it got accurate.

Comment: The 'lost' rep should be put into a fund and used to pay the 2-reps for bulk-downvotes of all 20K+ users who post grossly-obvious dup answers to bad questions to gain yet moar rep.

Comment: What if there is a user who has been a member of SO for several years but has contributed very little? . Then one fine day one of his posts goes boom! (in a good way) and he gets lots of previleges?