# Changing the daily rep limit to carry forwarded lost rep

Tags: feature-request, daily-reputation-limit

I have reached this limit and realized that after this limit there is no incentive to keep posting as there is no reputation gain.

Having understood that the limit is there to prevent new users like me from gaining to much power, shouldn't this rep gain from hitting the limit be carried over to the next day since it serves the same purpose, rather than it being wasted?[image]

Comment: Why actually? What would be improved? I think there are reasons for rep limitations.

Comment: I understand the reasons for the limitations, however, from what I have seen the reason is to limit the user from gaining power too fast, holding the rep and awarding it to the user the next day would be the same thing, no?

Comment: Giving it to you the next day wouldn't prevent you from gaining the privileges fast. It would, in fact, be like not having the cap at all. The only way it wouldn't is if you were hitting the rep cap every single day before the change.

Comment: Assuming that a user gets 1000 on the first day, for whatever reason,
he will take 5 days to use finish his 'quota', Since the rep to get high power requires around 2.5k rep, divided by 200, will still require a couple amount of days.

Comment: Alright, we'll roll with that example. Say they got 1000 rep from upvotes the first day, and nothing else for a week. In our model, they have to work for the several privileges they would unlock at 1000 rep. In yours, they make one or two goods posts and in that week, despite no other contributions of equal quality (if they make any at all), this user has 1k rep. The limit and wanting to slow down privilege gain is so you have to learn the system, and not just get lucky with one or two posts, to be able to use powerful tools.

Comment: If your *only* incentive to post content is the reputation, then that's a serious problem.  It's fine if it's *some* incentive, but if it's the *only* incentive it's a strong sign that you're going to have serious problems as a contributor here.

Comment: By the looks of it, it isn't that easy to hit 1k rep on the first day, even for a new user. Let's say that he is some expert is some topic, and manages to get the votes/rep, wouldn't that proves that he somewhat deserves it as well?

Comment: @servy tbh it is a concern. but by the looks of how people are aggressively downvoting others due to rep, it is an open issue. Obviously if the intention was that, I wouldn't even be here asking for this.

Comment: Or let's say he's popular on a programming forum or something else, and a lot of those users have at least 15 rep. He links to them, he gets a flood of upvotes from his followers. A lot of upvotes does not prove one is an expert.

Comment: @Kendra Wouldn't that be a form of voting fraud?

Comment: Reputation is a measure of how much the system trusts you. I think it's reasonable for there to be a time component attached to how much a user is trusted.

Comment: I would read [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268919/215552) on a question of why there is a daily rep limit.

Comment: @Ctc You have provided no basis for that assertion.  What makes you think people vote on posts based on the rep of the author?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. There's even a badge set for linking to a post and having a number of unique visits from it. If the user just says, "Hey, I posted an answer on SO" and links to it, there's no fraud. He's just sharing a link.

Comment: @Ctc If someone else decides to upvote all of that user's posts just because of who he is, then *that* user has committed voting fraud.  It is by no means fraud to link to, or mention, a post of yours through some external medium.

Comment: Therotically, I could just pay or make 20 different accounts to 'get rep' in this case?

Comment: @Ctc sure, but, it's very likely you'd get caught.

Comment: Feel free to try that- Others have. That's called sock-puppeting, and that _is_ fraud. The mods have tools to catch that.

Comment: im lost with this discussion. please refer to my question above

Comment: tbh i have no intention to try that. no one has time for that

Comment: For example: I drop my wallet some place and a stranger returns it and it even still has the cash in it. That shows some trustworthiness and ethics on their part. Does that mean I'm going to hand them the keys to my home? Of course not because *I still only just met them*.

Comment: @BSMP Thanks for a constructive answer that at least makes sense.

Answer (score 18):

> Having understood that the limit is there to prevent new users like me from gaining to much power

This is completely wrong.

If anything, the limit is there for the *exact opposite reason*. New users rarely hit the rep limit, while many "power" users hit the rep limit constantly and the most prolific users reliably hit the rep cap *every single day*, regardless of whether they visit the site.

The reputation cap *helps* new users by providing an incentive for the rep-obsessed users to *stop* contributing, giving the less-obsessed users a chance.

It *does* prevent new users from gaining too much power **too quickly**, and that's a good thing. We want to throttle access to the various moderator-esque privileges that rep eventually unlocks. However, the primary goal of the reputation cap is simply to encourage the overly rep-focused user to *stop posting*.

Comment: As a note on this, while it does prevent new users from getting privs too quickly, I only know of one instance of a new user where that was actually a limiting factor. Usually for new users, The rep cap hardly matters.