# Why did this user not get that much reputation?

Tags: discussion

Just now, I stroll Stack Overflow, and find a user who has a high reputation, but I find a strange thing.

[image]

You see, the answer's reputation is more that his total reputation, but why does he not have that more reputation?

I don't think there are enough downvotes (every one is -2) to reduce the reputation.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268917/559745

Comment: or the user has cast a lot of answer downvotes. pretty sure i've lost that much or more rep from answer downvotes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are three possibilities.

- The answer may be Community Wiki, in which case they don't get reputation from it.
- The user may have hit the "rep cap" several times. If you reach 200 points on a day, you won't get past that, no matter how many upvotes you get. (Bounties are the exception).
- And as David Postill points out in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346571/why-did-this-user-not-get-that-much-reputation/346574?noredirect=1#comment462772_346574), the user may have given away a lot of bounties.

The are two other ways in which a user may lose a lot of rep, but they're not likely in this case:

- It's possible that the user has posts that are deeply downvoted. For this case that's unlikely to be the cause - upvotes give more reputation than downvotes take.
- people get a 100 point reputation penalty if they post spam, but that's probably not the case here. If a user had posted spam often enough to cause a drop of this many points, their account would long have been suspended and/or deleted.

Comment: I think I know the reason now.

Comment: Reputation from accepted answers is also not counted for the rep cap.

Comment: He may also have awarded lot of bounties ...

Comment: The answer is a Community Wiki. [This is the answer being discussed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/189134)