# Do the reasons that the daily rep cap was imposed actually apply to high-rep users?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Closely related (but not identical): [Why is there a daily reputation limit of 200 points?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268901/why-is-there-a-daily-reputation-limit-of-200-points)

Also related (but also not identical): [Revisiting the rep cap (yes, again)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059/revisiting-the-rep-cap-yes-again)

The two posts I link to explain the reasons that we have the daily rep cap in the first place. Most of the answers focus either on "incentivizing further participation" and "making sure that people don't get privileges too quickly." The argument for the second one is that if a new user asks a particularly good question or posts a particularly good answer early on and garners a lot of upvotes on it, it doesn't necessarily imply that they know how to use the site. This is a legitimate point - I did see a user recently garner 400+ points by posting a very good first question that garnered approximately 100 upvotes over a few days.

A third argument is that it incentivizes people to write answers that get accepted (or, by extension, get awarded bounties) because those are the only way to get more than 200 reputation in a day.

With that said, do either of those first two arguments actually apply to higher-reputation users? Once you hit, for example, 3000 reputation, I'd hope you knew how to use the site well, and the only substantial privileges after that are the 10K tools and being able to view site analytics. At that point, you're also (hopefully) not just posting for the reputation. I'd also expect that that would be even more the case once you hit 10K rep.

The third argument would admittedly still apply, assuming that you still care about the reputation after you hit 10K rep (which may or may not be the case).

That being the case, do the first two reasons (incentivize further participation and prevent people from getting privileges too quickly) actually hold for high-reputation users?

Does anyone really benefit from limiting how much reputation Jon Skeet can get per day, for example? (Especially given that he can already, [among other things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts), recite Pi backwards, track down bugs just by staring at the code until it confesses, divide by zero, and count to infinity). According to one of the linked posts, at one point he would've been getting about 1000 reputation per day if it weren't for the rate cap; granted, that's a lot, but would he actually post less if he were getting 1000 rep per day vs. 200 per day? Would him getting 1000 rep per day actually hurt anything?

**Note:** I'm not asking about the purpose of the reputation cap in general or proposing that we change anything about how it works now, I'm just asking if the two reasons I mentioned above actually apply to high-rep users.

Comment: Since, by your own supposition, the higher rep users *don't care about getting rep* (not that that always holds, but it often does), they tautologically *don't care* and have no reason to oppose the current system.  That the current rules are more relevant and important for newer users rather than older ones isn't even necessarily a bad thing, or a reason to change them.

Comment: @Servy My point isn't so much that they don't care about the rep as much as it is that it won't necessarily hurt anything if they got rep faster. Consider: would you actually post less frequently if you could get rep faster than 200 points per day? I just don't think that that applies anymore once you hit a certain point.

Comment: I don't hit the 200 a day cap anyway, so i wouldn't care if it were raised or lowered.

Comment: But considering you're arguing that they wouldn't care either way *there's no reason to do anything*, because, by your own assumption, they don't care.

Comment: To me, the main reason why there is a cap has always been so very active SO contributors don't forget there are other, more important things in life.

Comment: @Servy I'm *not* arguing that they wouldn't care - I'm just asking if the two particular arguments I mentioned (that people might get privileges too quickly and that people might not participate as much) actually apply to high-rep users.

Comment: i mean, it might to some. if you replace "privileges" with "swag" or prestige once there are no more privileges to obtain.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I can't seee how the rep cap. or lack of it, affects beer or pizza?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Beer and pizza are both much more enjoyable once you've hit the rep cap for the day.

Comment: @TinyGiant I find that the only SO activity that increases the pleasure from beer/pizza is running out of close-votes:)

Comment: *At that point, you're also (hopefully) not just posting for the reputation.* - It does still cost rep to down vote answers and you don't keep your privileges if you dip back below those thresholds. So I'd imagine most users would care until they're not a few down votes away from losing the privilege they want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first reason, making sure that people don't get privileges too quickly, obviously doesn't apply to high-rep users. They already have all the privileges they're going to get without becoming a moderator or an employee of Stack Overflow.

The second reason, incentivizing further participation, does apply *if they still care about reputation*. As you said, the only way to get more than 200 reputation in a day is to keep providing the best answers so you get bonus reputation when answers are accepted, or by hunting bounties. So yes, it does benefit the community to limit the amount of reputation Jon Skeet can get in a day *if he still cares about reputation*. If he were getting 1000 rep per day for old answers, he'd have little incentive to keep making sure his new answers were of acceptable quality.