# Should reputation gain from individual posts be capped?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting

My reputation on Stack Overflow has skyrocketed since I gave a trivial, but popular answer to a frequently-viewed question, and it got hundreds of upvotes.

This seems unfair, because it incentivises making a few replies to popular questions (easy) rather than putting in the effort to reply to larger numbers of more obscure ones (more time consuming, but more helpful, and healthy for the site).

Could we perhaps cap the amount of reputation received from a particular post (say only count the first n upvotes, 10 or 25, or so) to avoid this? If so, it ought to be done retroactively, to avoid being unfair on new users.

Edit: Another idea would be a logarithmic reputation scale, so that the first 10 votes would have the same reputation impact as the next 100, and so on (assuming base 10 log). This still rewards popular answers, but not so disproportionately as at present.

Comment: This is (IMO) exactly what community wiki is for.

Comment: The community wiki does avoid this problem, but it requires a user to opt into it, so it's not a general solution, and it only works for the humble.

Comment: *it incentivises making a few replies to popular questions (easy)* - Is it easy to do this *on purpose* though? How would you know ahead of time that your answer was going to get that kind of attention?

Comment: I think something like this kind of makes sense for trivial answers that got lots of votes because people were happy that they found an answer easily. But what about non-trivial answers that got lots of votes because they're awesome? Why shouldn't they get all the rep? And how would the system be able to tell the difference?

Comment: @BSMP Look at the number of upvotes on the question?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202652/life-isnt-fair

Comment: @Don't Panic Yeah, I am concerned about that. The problem is you basically can't distinguish algorithmically. That said, even a single really good answer shouldn't have such a disproportional impact.

Comment: @Andrea So you wait until a question has a ton of up votes, which means it likely has multiple answers at that point, and then post an answer that's better than (or at least different from) the existing ones. Whether that's easy depends on the number and quality of the existing answers then, doesn't it?

Comment: @BSMP Or just age, as in my case. I can relatively easily get reputation by replying to old questions with new answers. Getting rep for that is fair, but the disproportionate amount doesn't feel so.

Comment: Apparently I've been doing it wrong.

Comment: I actually do think it should be capped, this is something I've thought about for a while, but not for the reasons stated here, and not in the manner stated here. I've got a pretty good case for it built up, but only regarding certain posts, where the feedback loop caused by *high score* -> *preference to appear in Related list* -> *views attract votes and raise score* gets certain older posts in a situation where the author is hitting the cap every day, forever, regardless of activity. The loop is a resonant combination of a few systemic quirks. This would only apply to *very* few cases.

Comment: Related (but poorly received) question: [Do the reasons that the daily rep cap was imposed actually apply to high-rep users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349214/do-the-reasons-that-the-daily-rep-cap-was-imposed-actually-apply-to-high-rep-use)

Answer (score 6):

So what? You found a way to get high reputation by answering popular questions with a simple solution that helps a lot of users. Good for you! I don't see anything unfair here.

What about downvotes - Is it fair to get a lot of them? You can easily get massively downvoted by answering this type of questions, but you obviously know your game and provide good answers.

Bottom line - We should not average/limit the reputation for the "benefit" of the less fortunate users with lower reputation.

Answer (score -1):

There is a natural limit for it: 100 votes. It also gives you a gold badge.

IMHO, this would be a really good proposal. And it would prevent the reputation numbers to be deformed by stray "how to add numbers in javascript?" answer, that gets 4000+ votes.

Gaining 1000 + 15 rep for an answer would be a reasonable number, and if someone really want, they can just give additional bounties. It would actually encourage that behavior.

Comment: Not really an objection, but it is worth noting that a 100 score cutoff is only relevant for sufficiently popular tags. In the ~32k questions tag I patronise, for instance, there have been only 91 answers with score >= 100, and only one over the past two years.

Comment: @duplode I think that's arguably a point in favour: why should we give more rep to people who answer questions regarding more popular languages?

Comment: @Andrea That's a good point.